# Multiple options for query from select menu

Tags: mysql, select, input

I have a search area which contains 3 field, one is an input field and the other two are drop down menus.  Either someone enters something into the input field or they select from BOTH of the drop downs (state and city).

Input search works fine. Select menus do not.

Here is the form.

```
<form name="ffl_finder" method="get" action="index.php">
  Enter a Zip Code to find a Firearms Dealer near you: &nbsp;<br />
  <input name="q" type="text" id="q" size="40">

  Select a State AND a City<br />
  <select name="qoption2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select . . .</option>

<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT state from ffl_list order by state asc";
$rs_results2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

while ($rrows2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results2)) {
?>

    <option value="<?php echo $rrows2[state]; ?>"><?php echo $rrows2[state]; ?></option>

<?php
    }
?>          
  </select>

  <select name="qoption3">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select . . .</option>

<?php

$sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT city from ffl_list order by city asc";
$rs_results3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());

while ($rrows3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results3)) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rrows3[city]; ?>"><?php echo $rrows3[city]; ?></option>

<?php
    }
?>          
  </select>
  <input name="doSearch" type="submit" id="doSearch" value="Search">                        
</form>
```

Here is the query:

```
    <?php if ($get['doSearch'] == 'Search') {

    //$cond2 = '';
  if($get['qoption2'] != '') {
  $cond2 = "`state` = 'qoption2'";
  }
//$cond3 = '';
  if($get['qoption3'] != '') {
  $cond3 = "`city` = 'qoption3'";
  }                         

  if($get['q'] == '') { 
  $sql = "select * from ffl_list where $cond2 and $cond3 order by state asc, city asc"; 
  }
  else { 
  $sql = "select * from ffl_list where `zip` = '$_REQUEST[q]' ORDER BY `id` asc";     
  } 
      $rs_results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    } ?>
```

I need the query to search both city and state and I cannot seem to get the conditions right. I know this is a lot of code but if someone could help that would be great.

Thanks,

Clint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        while ($rrows2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results2)) 
        {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rrows2['state']; ?>"><?php echo $rrows2['state']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

`state` and `city`may be cols' names of the ffl_list table, you have to use a string a key of the returned array from `mysql_Fetch_array`. You did wrong for `$rrows2` and `$rrows3`

When you create your filter for the query, you set a hard string, not GETted data :

```
  $cond2 = '';
  if($_GET['qoption2'] != '') {
     $cond2 = "`state` = '".$_GET['qoption2']."'";
  }
```

Comment: Great thanks!  Any idea on how to make the list of cities only show from the state selected?

Comment: If you want to change the cities-list on change of the choice of the state, you have to use Javascript and AJAX, and add function to onChange event of the states-list. On Change, you make an ajax request to select cityies from `ffl_list ` where state is the one selected.
2nd choice :  first page with state list, second page with cities list (filtered by state choosen)

Comment: I like the idea of the ajax and javascript. Can you help me with that or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is one way to do it : Create a AJAX request (JQuery is easy to use) from a  Javascript function. Data send to the request is the state choosen by user. The AJAX request make an HTTP request on a PHP page which print cities from the posted state (state is set in the data send to the AJAX request).
Create a function which update the cities-list from the output got from the PHP page. Something like `var req = $.ajax ({url: "gotCities.php", date: "state="+choosenState}); req.done (function (res) { /* Update list from output res */});`